# Compile-time constructor selection

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to implement the following API :

```
geojson::position_t<> point_1{ 10, 12 };
geojson::position_t<> point_2( 11, 13 );
geojson::position_t<> point_3(std::pair<int, int>(12, 14));

geojson::position_t<> line_1{ 
   geojson::position_t<>{ 100, 120 }, 
   geojson::position_t<>{ 110, 130 } };

geojson::position_t<> poly_1{
  { geojson::position_t<>{ 100, 120 }, geojson::position_t<>{ 110, 130 }}, 
  { geojson::position_t<>{ 101, 121 }, geojson::position_t<>{ 111, 131 }} };
```

The idea is to have **position_t<>** template class with the following properties :

- have some internal `value_type` identifying whether it is point or
  line
- have constructors and use SFINAE to identify if a point-type or
  line-type can be created based on passed parameters to ctor
- have method `value_type get() const {...}` returning point or line type
  depending whether point or line ctor was invoked

My first approach was to use boost::variant but I'm stuck how to get `value_type` and implement `get()` method.

The second attempt was to use partial template specialization. But so far, I didn't succeed with it.[wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tOl5Mgiey9cCiS7G)

Could somebody suggest approach how to achive required API ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a single class, you want to store it in std container?

Comment: This is impossible. If `value_type` is at compile time, you have to get 2 different classes.

Comment: Shold API be like this? Usually  such things are implemented as class Point and abstract class Shape storing container of points, and classes Line, Rect etc. inheriting from Shape.

Comment: Why do you want one type to behave, in different circumstsances, as if it is more than one type?

Comment: Well, maybe I do have a wrong design and requirements. I didn't want to implement runtime polymorphic classes and wanted to achieve reqsult using SFINAE/type deduction rules.

Comment: Can you use C++17 ? Then you might use deduction for `position_t<point>` versus `position_t<line>`.

Comment: Yes, C++17 is ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, you may use deduced guide, so you have both `position_t<Point>` and `position_t<Line>` and according to parameter constructor, choose the correct one.

Something like:

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Line
{
public:
    Point start;
    Point end;
};

template <typename T> class position_t;

template <>
class position_t<Point>
{
public:
    position_t(int x, int y) : point{x, y} {}
    position_t(const std::pair<int, int>& p) : point{p.first, p.second} {}

    const Point& get() const { return point; }
private:
    Point point;  
};

template <>
class position_t<Line>
{
public:
    position_t(const position_t<Point>& start,
               const position_t<Point>& end)
        : line{start.get(), end.get()}
    {}

    const Line& get() const { return line; }
private:
    Line line;  
};
```

And then the deduction guide

```
position_t(int, int) -> position_t<Point>;
position_t(std::pair<int, int>) -> position_t<Point>;
position_t(const position_t<Point>&, const position_t<Point>&) -> position_t<Line>;
```

So:

```
geojson::position_t point_1{ 10, 12 }; // geojson::position_t<Point>
geojson::position_t point_2( 11, 13 ); // geojson::position_t<Point>
geojson::position_t point_3(std::pair<int, int>(12, 14)); // geojson::position_t<Point>

geojson::position_t line_1{ // geojson::position_t<Line>
    geojson::position_t{ 100, 120 },   // geojson::position_t<Point>
    geojson::position_t{ 110, 130 } }; // geojson::position_t<Point>
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2881ed01948681be)

Comment: Thanks a lot for example - that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two optional solutions:

The first one uses standard polymorphism, it uses a base class `GraphicBase`.
The second approach is to use std::variant to keep the objects. If used that, you can remove the base class and virtual functions. As read from your comment, you see type deduction rules as a solution. Yes, my example work that way!

It has some pro and cons for vtable polymorphism versus tagged union as std::variant. Both is possible!

A remark on:

> have some internal value_type identifying whether it is point or line

You do not need some additional identifier, because the variant itself contains already that type tag. A variant is simply a union and a additional data entry which keeps track of the actual assigned type. Exactly what you want! You can use these tag with `std::visit` to call any function which the corresponding type passed to the function object you pass. ( In my example I use a generic lambda to make dispatching quite easy.

Hint:
Don't think about SFINAE if a simple overload or a specialization is possible!

```
class GraphicBase
{
    public:
        virtual void Print()=0;
        // for using with vtable polymorphism
        GraphicBase* Get() { return this; }
};


class Point: public GraphicBase
{
    public:
        Point( int, int ){}

        void Print() override { std::cout << "Point" << std::endl; }
        void PrintNonVirtual() { std::cout << "Point" << std::endl; }
};

class Line: public GraphicBase
{
    public:
        Line( Point, Point ){}
        void Print() override { std::cout << "Line" << std::endl; }
        void PrintNonVirtual() { std::cout << "Line" << std::endl; }
};


template < typename T >
class Graphics: public T
{
    public: 
        using T::T;

        // for using with variants
        T GetNonVirtual() { return static_cast<T>(*this);}
};  

Graphics( int, int ) -> Graphics<Point>;
Graphics( Point, Point ) -> Graphics<Line>;

int main()
{
    Graphics p1(1,1);
    Graphics l1({1,2},{3,4});

    // using vtable polymorphism
    std::vector<GraphicBase*> v;
    v.push_back( &p1 );
    v.push_back( &l1 );

    for ( auto el: v ) el->Print();

    // using the Get() to get the base pointer
    GraphicBase* ptr;
    ptr = p1.Get();
    ptr->Print();

    ptr = l1.Get();
    ptr->Print();

    // or using variants:
    using VT = std::variant< Point, Line >;

    std::vector<VT> var;
    var.push_back( p1 );
    var.push_back( l1 );

    for ( auto& el: var )
    {
        std::visit( []( auto& v ){ v.PrintNonVirtual(); }, el );
    }

    // here we get a copy of the object ( references not allowed in variants! )
    VT va1 = p1.GetNonVirtual();
    VT va2 = p1.GetNonVirtual();

    std::visit( []( auto& v ){ v.PrintNonVirtual(); }, va1 );
    std::visit( []( auto& v ){ v.PrintNonVirtual(); }, va2 );
 }
```